# Bash script to chose based on user input

Tags: bash, shell

#### Problem:

I need to make this bash script to choose based on the user inputs. Example how can i add choices? such that user just select from 1 to 3 and that is set in variable CLUSTER_NAME.

choices are test.com, try.com and me.com

---

#### Script

```
#!/bin/bash
sops_ops() {
    sops --version
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "proceed sops ops"
    else
        echo "check sops binary"
    fi

    read -p 'Enter cluster_NAME: = ' CLUSTER_NAME
    test_environment="test.com"
    test1_environment="test1.com"
    test2_environment="test2.com"

    case "${$CLUSTER_NAME}" in
      prod.$test_environment) ;;
      dev.$test1_environment) ;;
      stage.$test2_environment) ;;
      test.$test_environment) ;;
      *) echo "Invalid option: ${CLUSTER_NAME}" 1>&2 && exit 1 ;;

    if [ $CLUSTER_NAME = test.$test_env ];then
        printf "got cluster $CLUSTER_NAME"
    elif [ $CLUSTER_NAME = "test.test.com" ];then
        printf "got dev cluster $CLUSTER_NAME"
        echo "not found cluster"
    else
        echo "Environment not available"
    fi
}
sops_ops
```

#### Question:

How do I do that?

---

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do **what**? I don't understand the question. Your script is already using user's input for its decision.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: I see. `bash` already has a special construct for exactly this. Instead of `read` and `case`, do a `select`. See the bash man page for _select_, in the section labelled _Compound Commands_.